# How to create a public static bool function like "GetKeyDown();"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title says...

I have a mobile swipe function and it's:

```
VectorZ firstPos:
VectorZ lastPos:

void Update (){

   foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
      if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
         firstPos = touch.position;
         lastPos = touch.position;
      }

      if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
         lastPos = touch.position;
      }    

      if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {

         if((firstPos.x - lastPos.x) > 60)
         {
            //..Left swipe.
         }
         else if((firstPos.x - lastPos.x) < -60)
         {
            //..Right swipe.
         }
         else if((firstPos.y - lastPos.y) < -75)
         {
            //..Up swipe.
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So I'm trying to create a public static bool function that returns true once, like GetKeyDown();.

I wish to have like a "MobileMovement.SwipedUp();" or something and it works very very similar to "Input.GetKeyDown();" but this time, with a swipe movement using the swipe function that I have.

I tried doing it myself but I'm honestly too newbie for this.

Would anyone give me a hand, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unity already has functionality for swiping, you use `OnBeginDrag()`, `OnDrag()`, and `OnEndDrag()`

You have to put `using UnityEngine.EventSystems;` and `using UnityEngine.GUI`

then you inherit your class from the interfaces `IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler`

so it would look like this:

```
class MyClass : IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        // Started dragging
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    { 
        // Is dragging
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        // Finished dragging
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't heard of that yet. Is that for GUI, mostly? What I'm trying to do is to make my own public static bool function for my character, triggers, etc.. Like, if (MobileMovement.SwipedUp()) { //Jump }. Or like, if (MobileMovement.SwipedUp()) { //Trigger this timer }.

Comment: Its built for the new GUI system, yes, but what you are doing has everything to do with GUI, you really shouldn't handle swiping any other way. Make a canvas with a full screen size panel and put the above script on it, and handle all of your swiping logic from there.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the quick replies! I'll try to practice using this now. Is there any guide, documentation, or an example script using this to help me out a bit?

Comment: Unfortunately Unity API has weak documentation on their new GUI system, probably because they are still working out the minor kinks, so i wouldnt recommend looking there, but using the script and info i gave you should be enough for some debug/printing trial and error. Use the passed data variable for information like `data.point` if i remember correctly is mousepoint... And so on

Comment: I realized that there's a "data.position" variable. Is that the same as the "touch.position" on the script I had? _Edit: Currently debugging variables on each functions to see what's up._

Comment: Wow! Nvm my questions! Everything is working perfectly and it's quite simple! Thank you soooooo much, Andrew for telling me this. You literally saved my lifeeeeee.

Comment: Hah no problem my friend glad to help!

Comment: I still have one more question though. At this part:
`if((firstPos.x - lastPos.x) > 60) {                
   swipedLeft = true;
}`. How do I make swipedLeft return true _once_ then goes back to false in the next frame? Kinda like the GetKeyDown function.

Comment: `bool directionCalled = false;` < goes in your global vars `if((firstPos.x - lastPos.x) > 60 && !directionCalled) { swipedLeft = true; directionCalled = true; }` then make `directionCalled` false in the `OnEndDrag` function.

Comment: Oh, swipedLeft is a public static bool that if it returns true, the character will move to the left. What happens with that code is that if I hold down my finger to the left, my character will infinitely move to the left until I lift my finger up.

Comment: did u make an `else swipedLeft = false;`?

Comment: Ohoho, I did now and it works. Welp, that's it. Everything I need on this thread has been answered. Thank you once again, Andrew!